# Sorting a randomly generated 2 Dimensional Array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to make a program that prints out an 2 Dimensional array in ascending order throughout the entire array. Any of the elements in the array can not be repeating anywhere in the array. Anything you need to do to make it work is greatly appreciated.

08 11 14 19 21 22 25
15 22 25 28 32 37 41
20 28 31 32 39 40 48
24 34 41 47 53 54 56
28 37 47 50 57 60 66
29 38 50 57 64 70 71
31 43 52 62 65 75 78

It is gererated with the followint code but isn't sorted:

```
public static int[][] getRandomSorted2DArray(int size)
{
    int bigger = (int)Math.pow(2, size) + 1;
    int[][] data = new int[bigger][bigger];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = new java.util.Random().nextInt(90);
        }
    }        
    return data;
}
```

Again I need help with this program but needs two things.
1. Sort the entire array in ascending order.
2. No repeating any of the other elements.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem or a homework challenge

Comment: what are you thoughts about how this could be done?

Comment: Transform it 1D array and use Arrays.sort(), then re-transform it 2D.

Comment: Don't you want to have a table of width and height equal `size`? You probably want `data` to be `new int[size][size]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a sorted array, by making each element at least 1 bigger than the last one:

Keep track of the last asserted value and, instead of a completely random number, choose a random number between `lastValue` and `99 - valuesToGo` (so there is still space left for the next numbers.
Maybe this works:

```
public static int[][] getRandomSorted2DArray(int size)
{
    int bigger = (int)Math.pow(2, size) + 1;
    int[][] data = new int[bigger][bigger];
    lastValue = 0;
    valuesToGo = data.length * data[0].length;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            data[i][j] = lastValue + 1 + new java.util.Random().nextInt(99 - 1 - lastValue - valuesToGo);
            lastValue = data[i][j];
        }
    }        
    return data;
}
```

The values might get a little distributed around 100, but I guess you'll be able to fix that yourself, if you want to.